# Function Fails 2 of 3 tests

Tags: javascript

I'm helping a friend write a function which will take a string of space-separated words and return the longest one, but my code fails 2 out the 3 tests used to check it.

These are the tests:

```
describe("test for longest function functionality", function() {
  it("should return correct output for normal strings", function() {
    expect(longest("A")).toEqual("A");
    expect(longest("I love Avatar")).toEqual("Avatar");
    expect(longest("The stupidities of youth")).toEqual("stupidities");
  });

  it("should return correct output for gibberish", function() {
    expect(longest("hgdydrxtfEq Rradsc tstsa taeWwwec fgdd")).toEqual("hgdydrxtfEq");
  });

  it("should work for sentences with numbers", function() {
    expect(longest("This is a sentence with a number 7685838788")).toEqual("7685838788");
  });
});
```

This is my solution so far:

```
function longest(str) {
  var longestStart = 0;
  var longestEnd = 0;
  var current = 0;
  var currentLength = 0;
  while (current < str.length) {
    if (str.charAt(current) == ' ') {
      if (currentLength > (longestEnd - longestStart)) {
        longestStart = (current - currentLength);
        longestEnd = current;
      }
      currentLength = 0;
    } else {
      currentLength++;
    }
    current++;
  }
  return str.substring(longestStart, longestEnd);
}
```

Comment: Please show which of your tests fails.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi  test 1 and 3 to be specific

Comment: Total Specs: 3 Total Failures: 2                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                       1 .  test for longest function functionality should return correct output for normal strings
Expected '' to equal 'A'.

Expected 'love' to equal 'Avatar'.
2 .  test for longest function functionality should work for sentences with numbers
Expected 'sentence' to equal '7685838788'.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do this by having a function like so:

```js
function longestSubstring(stringToSplit) {
  var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(" ");

  var longestString = arrayOfStrings[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
    if (longestString.length < arrayOfStrings[i].length) {
      longestString = arrayOfStrings[i];
    }
  }

  console.log(longestString);
}

longestSubstring("Hello my friend");
longestSubstring("1 12 123 1234 12345");
longestSubstring("aaaaaaah hello yell");
```

Comment: your code doesn't pass any of the tests, but i ran the code snippet and  it seemed to be working well. The test involving numbers, the string could be a sentence with numbers eg The boy has 12345 toys. it should return 12345 as the correct one and the test with gibberish eg jcads sfef rfgwrffrg it should return rfgwrffrg as the correct 1. @thedudeabides

Comment: @Wafaw123 the code doesn't pass any of the tests because I'm not returning anything. If you would like it to, you simply must adjust the console.log in the function to actually be a return statement.

Comment: @Wafaw123 This is because Karma and Jasmine, which it appears you are using to run the tests, is expecting the function to return the longest string but it doesn't since nothing is returned. If there are portions of the code you don't understand please ask as I would be more than happy to explain in detail what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You're not processing after the string ends. Try adding this code at the end too:

```
if (currentLength > (longestEnd - longestStart)) {
  longestStart = (current - currentLength);
  longestEnd = current;
}
```

Your code is not the simplest; you should use `String.prototype.split()` to achieve the code that is the easiest to understand.